# Как передать в шаблон компонента Vue асинхронно получаемые данные не делая их реактивными

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

Вот предельно упрощенный код:

```
<template>
  dict_posts.length={{ dict_posts.length }}
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  setup() {
    let dict_posts: { id: number; value: string }[] = [];
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/dict_posts').then(resp => dict_posts = resp.data);
    return {dict_posts}
  }
}
</script>
```

Мне нужен словарь должностей, для использования в шаблоне. Словарь немалый, неизменяемый. Если сделать переменную реактивной, насколько я понимаю, на это будут тратиться определенные ресурсы, а реактивность мне не нужна, т.к. он постоянный. Но он заполняется из базы, асинхронно. Как можно передать в шаблон переменную, только после того, когда она заполнится? В реактивном варианте все понятно.

```
const dict_posts = ref<{ id: number; value: string }[]>([]);
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/dict_posts').then(resp => dict_posts.value = resp.data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается с помощью асинхронной функции setup

```
  async setup() {
    const dict_posts: { id: number; value: string }[] =
        (await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/dict_posts')).data;
    return {dict_posts}
  }
```

Но при использовании компонент необходимо обрамлять тэгом **suspense**, иначе выходит ошибка:

> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Учитывая что компонент предполагается использовать во многих местах программы, это несколько нагружает код. Интересно, нельзя ли как-нибудь обойти? А то пока в голову пришло только объявить еще один компонент с шаблоном

```
  <suspense>
    <template #default>
      <мой_основной_компонент/>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>загрузка...</template>
  </suspense>
```

и использовать везде уже его, а это как-то не элегантно.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Если вам не нужна реактивность - просто объявите обычную переменную `const dict_posts: { id: number; value: string }[] = []`

Вариант 2. Если вам надо положить это в store то сделайте `Object.freeze(resp.data)` и данные так же не будут реактивными.

Вариант 3. Вариант с Object.freeze и ref `const dict_posts = ref<readonly { id: number; value: string }[]>(Object.freeze([{ id: 1, value: '' }]));`

Comment: Реактивность нужна однократная - ровно до того момента, как поступление данных отобразится в шаблоне. Заморозить идея наверно здравая, но как поймать момент, когда это можно сделать? В хуке onUpdate не проходит, т.к. таких переменных может быть несколько. Сочетания watch, onUpdate, специальных структур, указывающих какая переменная уже заполнилась и определенной логики, как то уж слишком громоздко...

Comment: Положите всё в store, работайте с axios в action, складывайте в state замороженное - это самый простой и правильный способ получить удовольствие и иметь хорошую структуру.

Comment: Так бытует мнение, что Composition API может заменить Vuex?

Comment: Не знаю кто там что бытует :). Я с кайфом юзаю Vuex в третьей вьюшке. Композишн апи распробовал и постоянно использую. Не знаю вообщем, я бы сложил всё в store.

Comment: Добавил 3 вариант с Object.freeze и ref. Не пробовал, но должно сработать.

Comment: Все же хочу пока попробовать придерживаться "не умножай сущностей без необходимости". Как то мне показался синтаксис Vuex несколько перегруженным, Единый источник истины легко организуется на основе любой необходимой структуры данных, удобно редактируется на основе use-функций.